# Reloading and saving items in tableviews

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reloaddata

So I am creating a tableview where I add (and delete) items. I am able to add and delete the items in the tableView but...there are some issues...

1. When I add an item it does not show up in the tableView until I close the simulator, but then when I close and relaunch the app it appears in the tableView.
2. When I add another item to the tableView and close the app, the old items are replaced by the new added item. So auto-deletes old items when a new item is added to the tableView.

   Naturally I want to save the existing items when I close the app, and I want to add the new items on top of the existing tableView items without having to close the app and relaunch...I am not sure what is wrong with my code...? Thank you in advance!

#### TableView

```
import UIKit

class PlaceTableVC : UITableViewController {

var placeList = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("list")  != nil {
        placeList = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("list") as![String]

    }

    self.tableView.delegate = self


}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 2
}


// Define number of different cells in the tableview

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(section == 0) {
        return 1
    }
    else {
        return placeList.count
    }
}


// Define number of different cells in the tableview

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    switch indexPath.section{
    case 0:
        let myProfile = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AddAPlaceButton") as! TableViewCell

        return myProfile
    default:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AddedPlaceCell") as! SecondTableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = placeList[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }  
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    let section = indexPath.section
    if(section == 0) {
        return 60
    }
    else {
        return 60
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        placeList.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(placeList, forKey: "list")
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        tableView.reloadData()  
    }
}

}
```

#### Add Item Code

```
import UIKit

var placeList = [String]()

class AddAPlaceModalVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

@IBAction func addItem(sender:AnyObject) {
    placeList.append(textField.text!)
    textField.text = ""

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(placeList, forKey: "list")

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.textField.delegate = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true

}

@IBAction func closeAddAPlaceVC(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your class "PlaceTable VC", try putting this function:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

And this function remove viewDidiAppear:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        placeList.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(placeList, forKey: "list")
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```